# Jquery cloning issue - clones shown only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

please, take a look at this code with comments:

```
// Some div with data, which need to be cloned in another place.
var currentMonth = $('.month');

currentMonth.on('click',function(e) {
    // Select items to clone
    var clons = $(this).parent().siblings().find('.year-dropdown').not('.clone').addClass('clone');

    // Clone them, and append to #all-events
    clons.clone().appendTo('#all-events');

    // Show this div, as it's hidden item, with posiition absolute.
    $('#all-events').show();

    // #all-events has span instide - X with class .closed sign to close this overlay.
    $('.closed').on('click',function() {
      // Empty #all-events elements inside.
      $('#all-events').hide().html('<span class="closed"></span>');
    });
});
```

Now, the question is: Why after first click on currentMonth, everything works fine - items are cloned, #all-events is shown as overlay with clones, but click on .closed (X) hides #all-events, and now, when I click again on currentMonts, overlay with X is shown, but without clones ?

Answer (score 3):

`.not('.clone').addClass('clone')`

First time round you are finding elements without class `clone` and then adding the `clone` class.

Second time round there are no elements without the class `clone` because you added `clone` to them all previously.

Comment: $('#all-events').hide().html('<span class="closed"></span>'); removes those elements from DOM, so there are no longer here, right ?

Comment: That will remove your clones from the DOM. But you, I assume not your intention here, are setting the `clone` class on the original `.year-dropdown` items. Did you mean to add the `.addClass("clone")` after the `.clone()`?